# php gd writing image on top other png image

Tags: php, gd, transparent

i am trying to implement a function which draw an image on top other image.
i always get the second image which is above with black background here is the code i am using

```
function writeImageOnImage($canvasImage, $x, $y, $drawnImage, $multiplyer = 1, $dynamicProperotions = false){
    if(is_resource($canvasImage)){
        $canvasImage = $canvasImage;
    }else{
        $canvasImage = imagecreatefrompng($canvasImage);
    }
    $drawnImageResource = imagecreatefrompng($drawnImage, true);
    $drawnImageResource = $drawnImageResource['image'];
    //imagecolortransparent($drawnImageResource, imagecolorallocate($drawnImageResource, 255, 255, 255));
    if($dynamicProperotions){
        $width = imagesx($drawnImageResource);
        $height = imagesy($drawnImageResource);
        if($multiplyer > 1){
            $width /= $multiplyer;
            $height /= $multiplyer;
        }
    }else{
        $width = 20;
        $height = 20;
    }
    imagealphablending($canvasImage, false);
    imagesavealpha($canvasImage, true);
    //imagecolorallocatealpha($canvasImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagecopy($canvasImage, $drawnImageResource, $x*$multiplyer, $y*$multiplyer, 0, 0, $width*$multiplyer, $height*$multiplyer);
    imagedestroy($drawnImageResource);
    return $canvasImage;
}
```

here is how i am calling this function

```
writeImageOnImage("test.png", 100, 100, "checkSign.png", 1, true);
```

the "checkSign.png" is created from output from a user html canvas (which gives a svg output).
i convert the svg image to png using Imagick and this code:

```
function createSvgImage($data, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $fileName){
    global $configuration;
    $result = array();
    $result["file"] = $fileName;
    $data = str_replace("data:image/svg+xml;base64", "", $data);
    $data = str_replace(" ", "+", $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $data = str_replace('stroke="#000000"', 'stroke="#004fca"', $data);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
    $attr = $xml->attributes();
    $size = [$maxWidth, $maxHeight];
    $widthRatio = intval($attr->width) / $size[0];
    $heightRatio = intval($attr->height) / $size[1];
    $image = new \Imagick();
    $image->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    if($widthRatio > $heightRatio){
        $image->setResolution(72 * ($size[0] / intval($attr->width)),72*((intval($attr->height)*$widthRatio) / intval($attr->height)));
        $image->readimageblob($data);
        $image->scaleImage($maxWidth,floatval($attr->height)/$widthRatio);
        $result['width'] = $maxWidth;
        $result['height'] = floatval($attr->height)/$widthRatio;
    }else{
        $image->setResolution(72*((intval($attr->width)*$heightRatio) / intval($attr->width)),72 * ($size[1] / intval($attr->height)));
        $image->readimageblob($data);
        $image->scaleImage(floatval($attr->width)/$heightRatio, $maxHeight);
        $result['width'] = floatval($attr->width)/$heightRatio;
        $result['height'] = $maxHeight;
    }
    $image->setimagetype(\Imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR);
    $image->setimageformat("png");
    /*$image->setOption('png:color-type', 6);
    $image->setOption('png:bit-depth', 8);*/
    //$image->writeimage("png16:".$fileName);
    $image->writeimage($fileName);
    return $result;
}
```

and this function is initiated using this code:

```
createCanvasImage($_POST['canvas'], 500, 500, "checkSign.png");
```

here is the [output image i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S12yF.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so figure out why your `$canvasImage` isn't what it should be. We can't help with that, since you haven't shown anything of HOW this function of yours is called.

Comment: @MarcB i edited my question now it includes all the code i am using to create anything from here.
and also my canvas image is created from TCPDF (i am outputing the first page of a pdf file to image).